# Date comparison issue

Tags: apex, soql, datetime, date, formatting

I am implementing date functionality where i want to get records date within last 4th calender quarter.How can i achieve this in SOQL?

I have tried with date in `LAST_4_QUARTERS`, but am getting records from all past 4 quarters. I want to get records from past 4th Quarter only.

> Ex: today is 4th quarter 2013, I want to get records from only 4th
>   quarter of 2012.

`[select Name from Invoice_Line_Item__c where Invoice_Date__c  =: LAST_4_QUARTERS];`

Answer (score 1):

Few issues.

1. When using date literals in SOQL, you do not need to use the colon
   `:` that you normally use when referring to variables.
2. You should use the literal `LAST_N_QUARTERS:n`.  So, for your
   case it would be `LAST_N_QUARTERS:4`.

**So your final SOQL should be**

```
[Select Name From Invoice_Line_Item__c Where Invoice_Date__c = LAST_N_QUARTERS:4];
```

Here is the documentation you can look at

[http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm%27)

> **EDIT**

In looking closer at your question, it looks like you don't want the past 4 quarters but rather the fourth quarter of a date in the past (in your case, 1 year ago).  If you want to do this, then date literals likely wont be the way to go.

I would create new date instances, and use those in your SOQL.  Something like this

```
    Date beginDate = Date.newInstance(2012,10,1);
    Date endDate = Date.newInstance(2012,12,31);
    list<Invoice_Line_Item__c> invoices = [Select Name From Invoice_Line_Item__c Where
         Invoice_Date__c >=: beginDate and Invoice_Date__c <=: endDate];
```

Comment: Hey sfdc_ninja, i have tried your query, then am getting all records from last four quarters. i want to get 4th quarter records only. In second code snippet how can get start date and end date of current quarter dynamically?

Comment: Yes, I didn't read the question correctly, try the second query that I added, this should work.

Comment: how can get start date and end date of current quarter dynamically?

Comment: So, you want the quarter 4 back? Ie, in Q3 2013, you want Q3 2012?

Comment: This blog post seems to cover getting the dates for the current quarter.  http://forceguru.blogspot.com/2012/07/is-there-better-way-to-get-last-date-of.html

Comment: @thomas taylor you are right. i want to get records with date in last year quarter, i.e., current is Q4 so i want records date withing Q4 of 2012